# PHP breaks an array value if value has a space in it

Tags: php, twig

I have a PHP function called in a Twig template like:

```
{{ test({"data":{"event":"content interactions", "action":"clicked: bookmark"}}) }}
```

Where I pass an array into a PHP method to build a final string:

```
function test($attributes): string
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($attributes['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $result.=' data-attr-'.$key.'='.$value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The intended `$result` would be:
`data-attr-action="content interactions" data-attr-action="clicked: bookmark"`
But for some reason PHP is breaking the $value if it has a space in it, returning `data-ga-event="content" interactions="" data-ga-action="clicked:" bookmark=""`

What is my problem, causing the spaces to be treated as new lines? This entire concept works great if the `$value` is a string without a space - but unfortunately I cannot promise this.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the value in quotes? Like `$result.=' data-attr-'.$key.'="'.$value.'"';` Is _PHP_ breaking with some sort of error? Or is your HTML just not outputting how you'd expect because HTML attributes with spaces need to be quoted?

Comment: Possible reason you are getting data-attr-action=content interactions data-attr-action=clicked: bookmark - with no quotes, and your browser add it when inspect the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing double quotes in your function seem to cause this.
Without them the actual result is

`data-attr-event=content interactions data-attr-action=clicked: bookmark`

which confuses the processor because it's not clear where the next property starts as data attributes themselved are divided by spaces already

Try

```
function test($attributes): string
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($attributes['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $result.=' data-attr-'.$key.'="'.$value.'"';
    }
    return $result;
}
```